# Javascript function to detect different keyframes of videos

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I am developing a simple app where you can live compare two videos. A requirement for this project is that they are perfectly synced. I've done lots of research, and tried almost every single loaded event I could find over Stack Overflow, but no success. I have a new idea, I don't know if this is achievable with Javascript. First of all, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<video id="leftVideo" src="before.mp4" oncanplaythrough="leftVideoLoaded()" alt="before" loop="true" width="600" height="366"></video>
<video id="rightVideo" src="after.mp4" oncanplaythrough="rightVideoLoaded()" alt="after" loop="true" width="600" height="366"></video>
```

JS:

```
var leftVideoLoadedCheck = 0;
var rightVideoLoadedCheck = 0;
function leftVideoLoaded() {
    leftVideoLoadedCheck = 1;
}

function rightVideoLoaded() {
    rightVideoLoadedCheck = 1;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").beforeAfter();

    var leftPlayer = new MediaElement("leftVideo");
    var rightPlayer = new MediaElement("rightVideo");

    var refreashLoadedEvent = setInterval(function(){
        if(leftVideoLoadedCheck == 1 && rightVideoLoadedCheck == 1) {

            setTimeout(function() {
                leftPlayer.play();
                rightPlayer.play();
            }, 1000);

            clearInterval(refreashLoadedEvent);
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

Here is a live demo:

http://amarsyla.com/sandbox/beforeafter/

I got some good results, but if the videos keep looping a few times, they lose their syncing between them. Is there a way I can setup a function which runs every 500ms, and detects the keyframes of each video. When the keyframes are not the same, pause both videos, and start playing them again at one same keyframe. So, I am seeking for something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    firstVideoKeyframe = ...
    secondVideoKeyframe = ...

    if(firstVideoKeyframe != secondVideoKeyFrame) {
        firstVideo.pause();
        secondVideo.pause();

        var keyframeToPlay = Math.min(firstVideoKeyframe, secondVideoKeyframe);

        firstVideo.playAtKeyframe(keyframeToPlay);
        secondVideo.playAtKeyframe(Math.min(keyframeToPlay));
    }
}, 500);
```

I hope that's not something that only my imagination can do...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use threads in JS, so theoretically you could do this. Link with an example of how you could get this done : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=aDkF_uQvTn1

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. It has nothing to do with [key frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types#Intra_coded_frames.2Fslices_.28I.E2.80.91frames.2Fslices_or_Key_frames.29). You just want to synchronize videos, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, did you intend that comment for a different question?

Comment: @aldel : No, in my opinion the poster could actually use what is in that link to synchronize his videos.

Comment: @aldel Hmm, I don't see where my title is misleading. I need to detect if the current keyframes of two videos are different.

Comment: @AmarSyla, by keyframes do you mean I-frames (aka infra frames)? That's what keyframes would usually mean in this context. It's true that seeking to an I-frame is more efficient, but it doesn't seem to be what your question is fundamentally about. And no, there's no reasonable way to detect I-frames in JavaScript, last I knew. Maybe there's something buried in the Media Source Extensions or something.

Comment: Or you could use a video decoder written in JavaScript to find the I-frames (this could be done in a Web Worker... maybe that's what @NorbertvanNobelen was suggesting, because I don't see how workers are relevant otherwise). But that's a pretty heavyweight solution.

Comment: And by infra frames, of course, I meant intra frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with how well it works to call `.play()` on both videos at once, then the simplest solution may be to **not** use `loop="true"` to make the videos loop. Instead, detect when both videos have ended (using the `onended` event), and then play them both again. (You *might* need to seek to the beginning of both, then wait for `onseeked` on both, to make sure they're both ready to play.)

There is still a danger that one video will get behind the other, mainly because of buffering issues. You can detect where each video is in its playback by looking at `.currentTime`. If the two values of `.currentTime` are too far apart, then you'd want to assign one to be the value of the other. (Don't expect them to be exactly equal.)

The "correct" way to synchronize two videos is using a [MediaController](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#synchronising-multiple-media-elements), but as far as I know, no browser has implemented that yet. When they do, you can easily synchronize videos by setting the same value of the `mediagroup` attribute for both video elements (this automatically creates a `MediaController` and attaches it to both videos).

Comment: Thanks, this is some good info I can use. I also heard about mediagroup, but as you said, I couldn't get it working in any browser. Also, thanks a lot for pointing out to not use looping. I realized now that that can cause a lot of problems.